# Update IntraWeb 12 in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, intraweb

I performed the update IntraWeb 12.1.18 in Delphi-XE2, but he asked me the license number of iw ... Is this normal?

```
update
```

for those interested :

- Execute Delphi "Install, Repare and Remove" tool (or run the .iso with latest update pack)
- Uncheck IntraWeb and apply (wait for this long operation...)
- Download IntraWeb from atozed's [site](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/index.en.aspx)
- Register [here](http://www.atozed.com:9991/) and ask for Bundled License
- Execute the file provided that validate your installation and sends you the license by email
- Run IntraWeb Installer and paste the license from the email

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's normal. There's a few hoops to jump through to upgrade IntraWeb. You start [here](http://www.atozed.com/IntraWeb/Download/FreeKeyRequest.EN.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't thought it could be so simple !! it worked fine ^^